# How to increase the performance of WPF Application

Tags: wpf, performance, c#-3.0

I have developed WPF Application. In that application iam loading 200mb photos to the listbox.After that Iam adding those images to canvas.While adding photos to canvas after sometime (i.e; after adding 10mb images)iam getting Some error like ----

*****The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x10b46f0 to COM context 0x10b4860 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.*****

Is there any way to increase the performance of my application. I need a solution for this problem.

Any Suggestions for this.

Answer (score 5):

Don't load all 200 mb of photos into the listbox all at once on your UI thread.  Will the user be looking at 200 mb all at once?  It'll take some work on your part, but you're going to need to do some delayed loading of the images from a background thread.

Comment: Yes, user willbe looking at all the images into the listbox.Loading images into listbox is not a problem. iam using background thread for that. but the problem is while adding photos to the canvas. For adding also i used background worker.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like two questions, the first is that you are loading images in a background thread, but not doing it correctly; thus, the COM error. Double check that you are have a STAThread application and that the image loading thread is not interacting with the WPF dispatch thread incorrectly. Here's a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165316/stathread-and-multithreading) MTA vs. STA; however, WPF needs STA, and it's a loosing battle to fight it.

The second question seems to be how should one do this; that is, loading a bunch of images for display. I would look into using a lazy data binding of the ListView and let the virtualizing presenter that's built into is manage the loading/display of the images.

Here's some docs on using a [view-model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx). The viewmodel could coordinate the image load and provide the ListView with a binding source that would automatically get the application working.

A simpler alternative might be to start up a background thread and load the images into an ObservableCollection<>, bind that to the ListView and let the framework deal with the display.

I second what Greg D said, loading 200mb of images sounds like a recipe for problems.