# Process.Start is blocking

Tags: c#, process, blocking, sta

I'm calling Process.Start, but it blocks the current thread.

```
pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");

// Start process
mProcess = new Process();
mProcess.StartInfo = pInfo;
if (mProcess.Start() == false) {
    Trace.TraceError("Unable to run process {0}.");
}
```

Even when the process is closed, the code doesn't respond anymore.

But Process.Start is really supposed to block? What's going on?

*(The process start correctly)*

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Thread ServerThread = new Thread(AccepterThread);
            ServerThread.Start();

            Console.WriteLine (" ---  Press ENTER to stop service ---");
            while (Console.Read() < 0) { Application.DoEvents(); }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }

        public static void AccepterThread(object data)
        {
            bool accepted = false;

            while (true) {
                if (accepted == false) {
                    Thread hThread = new Thread(HandlerThread);
                    accepted = true;
                    hThread.Start();
                } else
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        public static void HandlerThread(object data)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting process.");

            // Start process
            Process mProcess = new Process();
            mProcess.StartInfo = pInfo;
            if (mProcess.Start() == false) {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to run process.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Still living...");
        }
    }
}
```

Console output is:

> ---  Press ENTER to stop service ---
>   Starting process.

---

Found it:

**[STAThread]**

Makes the Process.Start blocking. I read [STAThread and Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165316/stathread-and-multithreading), but I cannot link the concepts with Process.Start behavior.

AFAIK, STAThread is *required* by Windows.Form. How to workaround this problem when using Windows.Form?

---

*News for the hell:*

If I rebuild my application, the **first** time I run application work correctly, but if I stop debugging and restart iy again, the problem araise.

The problem is not raised when application is executed without the debugger.

Comment: Set `UseShellExecute` and `ErrorDialog` to true and see if there are any errors being generated.

Comment: Well given that we don't know what the "cDaemon" class does, it's kinda hard to tell what's going on. Please try to come up with a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: (That use of Application.DoEvents combined with Console.Read looks pretty suspicious though.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet Here is the working example. 'mProcess.Start' blocks, even if started process has been closed.

Comment: Found it: [STAThread] makes Process.Start blocking. Still workering why!

Comment: I have a WinForms application that calls `Process.Start` without blocking.

Comment: @Luca: No it doesn't. I've just applied it to my sample (see my answer) and it still doesn't block. Your example still isn't a *complete* example - it doesn't have a class declaration. I want something I can just cut and paste, and see it running. Ideally it should use Console.WriteLine instead of Trace for simplicity.

Comment: I've just fiddled around with your example to put all the using directives in etc, and it printed out "Still living" - i.e. it didn't block. Again, please create a short but *complete* example, and tell us what it does on your machine.

Comment: Actually Process.Start block on my box. But eliminating STAThread works perfectly.

Comment: @Luca: Weird. It prints "Still living" on my box.

Comment: See updates. Seems a timing problem... I can't believe in it.

Answer (score 13):

No, `Process.Start` doesn't wait for the child process to complete... otherwise you wouldn't be able to use features like redirected I/O.

Sample console app:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Process p = new Process { 
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe")
        };
        p.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("See, I'm still running");
    }
}
```

This prints "See, I'm still running" with no problems on my box - what's it doing on your box?

Comment: @CurtisWhite: It really doesn't normally. I suggest you ask a new question with a short but complete example.

Comment: I posted a new question regarding. One unique aspect is I display a form before the App.Run http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466758/process-start-block-application-run

Comment: Very strange behavior, I was able to resolve by launching the process start in its own thread. I had tried both using time delays on the start process and launch process, processing do events, etc. The launch process is run inside a C# scripting application NinjaTrader fyi.

Comment: You're right, I deleted my comment after a few minutes, but you must have seen it before my delete.

Comment: @SweatCoder: Yup. Will delete mine now, and then delete *this* one in a few more minutes.

Answer (score 7):

Create a [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) and set UseShellExecute to false (default value is true). Your code should read:

```
pInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
pInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

// Start process
mProcess = new Process();
mProcess.StartInfo = pInfo;
if (mProcess.Start() == false) {
    Trace.TraceError("Unable to run process {0}.");
}
```

I had the same issue and starting the executable creating the process directly from the executable file solved the issue.

Comment: +1 - Although for me an Excel workbook I was opening was blocking the thread. To open a particular workbook use ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "EXCEL.EXE";
            startInfo.Arguments = filePath

Comment: I've been trying to solve this issue for days, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same blocking behavior as the original poster in a WinForms app, so I created the console app below to simplify testing this behavior.

Jon Skeet's example uses Notepad, which only takes a few milliseconds to load normally, so a thread block may go unnoticed.  I was trying to launch Excel which usually takes a lot longer.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading;

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        WriteLine("About to start process...");

        //Toggle which method is commented out:

        //StartWithPath();  //Blocking
        //StartWithInfo();  //Blocking
        StartInNewThread(); //Not blocking

        WriteLine("Process started!");
        Read();
    }

    static void StartWithPath() {
        Process.Start(TestPath);
    }

    static void StartWithInfo() {
        var p = new Process { StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(TestPath) };
        p.Start();
    }

    static void StartInNewThread() {
        var t = new Thread(() => StartWithPath());
        t.Start();
    }

    static string TestPath =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) +
        "\\test.xlsx";
}
```

Calls to both `StartWithPath` and `StartWithInfo` block my thread in a console app.  My console does not display "Process Started" until after the Excel splash screen closes and the main window is open.

[image]

`StartInNewThread` will display both messages on the console immediately, while the splash screen for Excel is still open.

Comment: Ouch... Still anxious for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem when launching a .bat script that was on a network drive on a different domain (we have dual trusted domains).  I ran a remote C# debugger and sure enough Process.Start() was blocking indefinitely.

When repeating this task interactively in power shell, a security dialog was popping up:

[image]

As far as a solution, [this was the direction](https://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/28456-how-declare-locations-inside-your-local-network.html) we went.  The person that did the work modified domain GPO to accomplish the trust.

Answer (score 0):

Start server via command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress" /path:\Publish /port:8080
```

This take access to sub-threads of the tree process of OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch process and then make the process independent on the "launcher" / the originating call:

```
//Calling process
using (System.Diagnostics.Process ps = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
{
    try
    {
        ps.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Apps"; 
        ps.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"; //command
        ps.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\Apps\xyz.accdb"; //argument
        ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        ps.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        ps.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false; //display a windows
        ps.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("==> Process error <=={0}" + ex.ToString(), Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```