# Microsoft Real time protection crashes calling program with .NET Process.Start

Tags: c#, process.start, windows-defender

I have a software integration program that will launch other applications.  A recent Windows 10 update has resulted in the calling application locking up even though the other applications launch.
In my code, it is a simple statement.  I will use Notepad.exe as an example

```
 Process.Start(notepad.exe)
```

Nothing more than that.
Any suggestions?  I do know that there are settings in group policy editor that can turn this off.  However, having to do this with many customers is not an option.
Any suggestions?
Tom

Comment: You say "Microsoft Real time protection crashes" in the title, and "the calling application locking up".  Which is it?  Do you have an [mcve]?  If I run a console program that simply calls `Process.Start(notepad.exe)` in your environment, will it crash/lock-up?  Do you have any error messages shown?  Anything in the event log?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285229/832052

Comment: @Flydog57 keep reading... "Microsoft Real time protection crashes calling program", it's consistent

Comment: OK, so there is no lock-up, the calling program crashes?  A crash and a lock-up (aka a _hang_) are very different symptoms

Comment: Actually, the calling process keeps running in the background.  However, there is no longer a UI.  It must be killed with the task manager.

Comment: Are you simply calling your code from the UI, or a different thread?

Comment: The code is running in the UI, not a different thread.  However, the code that continues to run is in a background thread.  The UI never gets displayed after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9285229/832052) suggests disabling [UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=net-6.0). Try this

```cs
Process p = new Process() {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe") {UseShellExecute = false}};
p.Start();
```

Comment: I changed my code to this and the software launches . However, it will have to go to the customer with the issue to dfetermine if it is a fix.  Thanks,  something to look at.