# AccessViolationException in C# multithreaded form

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, access-violation

First off this is my first C# project. I have been working on this project for about 6 months.

We have a winforms program and it contains a logging GUI. In order to keep the rest of the program responsive I wanted to create the logging gui on a separate thread since it can be quite intensive when lots of stuff is going on.

This is how I attempted to open the the form on a new GUI thread. In general it works and keeps the main gui responsive. However we now randomly get a AccessViolationException (http://pastebin.com/7tLtBSei) when this is activated and I am at a loss.

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    loggingForm = new LoggingForm(Logger.path);
    Application.Run(loggingForm);
});
thread.Name = "LoggingFormGUIThread";
thread.Start();
```

The logging GUI just batch reads the log file and appends it to a RichTextBox. It doesn't touch any managed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the apartment state of the thread to STA.

```
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Name = "LoggingFormGUIThread";
thread.Start();
```

This is required for many user interface components (such as `RichTextBox`) to function correctly.

Comment: Thanks for a quick and helpful answer. This seems to have fixed the issue. I haven't quite wrapped my head around why this is needed yet though.

Comment: @DrWu Many UI elements use COM underneath, and this is required for the COM objects to function properly.  In general, you need to always make UI threads STA.

Comment: I found an explanation why here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies

Thanks again.