# AccessViolationException occured using P/Invoke with Media Foundation Interface in Multithread application

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, pinvoke

I'm using the P/Invoke in C# to call native function from C++ DLL as below:

1. C++ DLL:

   ```
       extern "C"
       {
           // Function: Create Wmv video from sequences image. Codec: WMV3 (VC-1)
           __declspec(dllexport) bool __stdcall CreateWMV(...)
           {
           ...
           }
       }
   ```
2. C# wrapper class. I create the C# wrapper class function to map with native C++ code:

   ```
       [DllImport("AVIEncoder.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateWMV", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
       public static extern bool createWmv(...);
   ```

I'm sure that the parameters were marshaling correctly in C#, because it would run successfully when I called directly in client C# code.
The issue only occurred when I put the function in background thread.

```
private void Test()
{
....
createWmv(...); // This call was processed without issue
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(
    new ThreadStart(()=>
    {
        createWmv(...); // This call causes AccessViolationException
    }
}
```

The function createWmv() uses the Media Foundation Interface to generate Wmv video. I tried to debug and I found out that when I commented out the function IMFSinkWriter::WriteSample() in native code, the program run without causing the exception.

Thus, I wonder whether Microsoft has something weird in SinkWriter implementation.
Does anyone have the same issue using Media Foundation this way?

Comment: I think we should look at your C++ code for more details. (It seems like a complex threading issue which has something to do with i.e. Window handles aor thread heap.)

Comment: Try setting [ApartmentState to STA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21488526/706456)

Comment: @oleksii thanks, It seems to be run with STA ApartmentState now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow oleksii's comment, I set below:

```
backgroundThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); // Add this to fix createWMV() in multithreading
backgroundThread.Name = "CreateVideoThead";
backgroundThread.Start();
```

Now, the program could run without exception. Thanks for the concept of [ApartmentState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.apartmentstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in C# threading.