# Python tkinter.filedialog askfolder interfering with clr

Tags: python, .net, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python.net

I'm mainly working in Spyder, building scripts that required a pop-up folder or file Browse window.

The code below works perfect in spyder.
In Pycharm, the `askopenfilename` working well, while `askdirectory` do nothing (stuck).
But, if running in debug mode - the script works well.
I tried to run the script from SAS jsl - same issue.

Any Idea what should I do?
Python 3.6
Pycharm 2017.2

Thanks.

The Code I'm using includes:

```
import clr #pythonnet 2.3.0
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import (askdirectory,askopenfilename)

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
PPath=askdirectory(title="Please select your installation folder location", initialdir=r"C:\Program Files\\")

t="Please select jdk file"
if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~\Documents')):
    FFile = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("jdk file", "*.jdk"),("All Files", "*.*")),title=t, initialdir=os.path.expanduser('~\Documents'))
else:
    FFile= askopenfilename(filetypes=(("jdk file", "*.jdk"),("All Files", "*.*")),title=t)

sys.path.append(marsDllPath)
a = clr.AddReference('MatlabFunctions')
aObj = a.CreateInstance('Example.MatlabFunctions.MatLabFunctions')
```

edit: seems like issue related to the pythonnet "imoprt clr", but I do need it in the code.

Similar question asked here: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/648

Comment: I tried this code on Python 3.6 Pycharm 2017.2 and it is working correctly for both folders and files. Are you sure that there is no errors appearing to you?

Comment: Thank you Ahmed.

Actually in my code I'm using pythonnet 2.3.0 to add reference.
So in the code I have "import clr" as well.
I tried to remove it and its worked well for me. but yet I need it...

I'll updtae the question.
Maybe it related to another clr object cojuvting with pythonnet clr?

Comment: the code doesn't work when it run from python command line

Comment: @constructor if you really want this resolved, try opening a bounty!

Comment: @denfromufa I added bounty.

Comment: What happens if you delay the clr import to after the dialog?

Comment: I see in the related github link the version being used is an Anaconda distro. Are you using Anaconda or a clean install of python 3.6?

Comment: @Mike-SMT I use Anaconda distributive.

Comment: @TarunLalwani when I move import clr after the dialog, it works. But we need define import and use clr also before dialog

Comment: @constructor, not a solution but i would try and do all the tkinter imports before importing clr and see if it solves the issue for the time being

Comment: I believe your issues may be caused by Anaconda and as such will probably not be easy to correct here. Anaconda is great for having many library ready to go but I have seen many bugs come from Anaconda. I would follow this link: [anaconda-issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues) and submit the report for your problem there.

Comment: @ItzikKaplan this might be a dumb idea but have you tried importing `clr` as something else. Say like this: `import clr as my_clr` and see if that helps. Maybe there is some kind of import conflict in the name space however I don't really see how that could be when you import as tk for tkinter.

Comment: By the way in your code you are missing the `import sys`. Is this in your original code? Without it `sys.path.append(marsDllPath)` wont work. If we could get an example jdk code for testing that would help.

Comment: just to confirm, using standard CPython (3.4) i get the same non working behaviour, i've tried different ways of importing the module, and both as a script and interactively, it seems as soon as the clr module is loaded it does something to the runtime, but not sure what...

Comment: @Mike-SMT `import clr as my_clr` doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is rather mediocre, although not so obvious. The problem is not in `tinker` or `pythonnet`, it stems from the COM threading model.

To begin with, since you're using the `clr`, let's try to use dialogs directly with it (it's not absolutely necessary to import the `tinker` module):

```
#   importing pythonnet
import clr

#   adding reference (if necessary) to WinForms and importing dialogs
#   clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import OpenFileDialog, FolderBrowserDialog

#   creating instances of dialogs
folder_dialog = FolderBrowserDialog()
file_dialog = OpenFileDialog()

#   try to show any of them
folder_dialog.ShowDialog()
file_dialog.ShowDialog()
```

As you can see, it hangs just like in your case. The reason, as was mentioned above, stems from the threading's apartment state([[1]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx), [[2]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693344(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Therefore the `clr` implicilty sets this state to MTA (Multi-threaded apartment), which can be tested via [`CoGetApartmentType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
#   importing ctypes stuff
import ctypes
get_apartment = ctypes.windll.ole32.CoGetApartmentType

#   comment/uncomment this import to see the difference
#   import clr

apt_type = ctypes.c_uint(0)
apt_qualifier = ctypes.c_uint(0)

if get_apartment(ctypes.byref(apt_type), ctypes.byref(apt_qualifier)) == 0:
    #   APPTYPE enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693793(v=vs.85).aspx
    #   APTTYPEQUALIFIER enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd542638(v=vs.85).aspx
    print('APTTYPE = %d\tAPTTYPEQUALIFIER = %d' % (apt_type.value, apt_qualifier.value))
else:
    print('COM model not initialized!')
```

However, many older COM objects, such as shell dialogs, require STA mode.
Good explanation about the difference between those two states can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta).

Finally, the solutions:

1) Use STA thread for dialogs:

```
#   importing tkinter stuff
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfilename

#   importing pythonnet
import clr

#   adding reference (if necessary) to WinForms and importing dialogs
#clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import OpenFileDialog, FolderBrowserDialog

#   adding reference (if necessary) to Threading and importing Thread functionality
#clr.AddReference('System.Threading')
from System.Threading import Thread, ThreadStart, ApartmentState


#   WinForms thread function example
def dialog_thread():
    folder_dialog = FolderBrowserDialog()
    file_dialog = OpenFileDialog()

    folder_dialog.ShowDialog()
    file_dialog.ShowDialog()

#   Tk thread function example
def tk_dialog_thread():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    askdirectory()
    askopenfilename()

#   check again apartment state at start
current_state = Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()
if current_state == ApartmentState.STA:
    print('Current state: STA')
elif current_state == ApartmentState.MTA:
    print('Current state: MTA')

#   start dialogs via CLR
thread = Thread(ThreadStart(dialog_thread))
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
thread.Start()
thread.Join()

#   start dialogs via Tkinter
thread = Thread(ThreadStart(tk_dialog_thread))
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
thread.Start()
thread.Join()
```

2) Force STA mode via [`CoInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`CoInitializeEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695279(v=vs.85).aspx) before CLR does so for MTA:

```
#   importing ctypes stuff
import ctypes
co_initialize = ctypes.windll.ole32.CoInitialize

#   importing tkinter stuff
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory, askopenfilename

#   Force STA mode
co_initialize(None)

# importing pythonnet
import clr 

#   dialogs test
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

askdirectory()
askopenfilename()
```

Comment: The suggested solution works for Windows dialogs, but usually doesn't work for tkinter with message `Unhandled Exception: Python.Runtime.PythonException: RuntimeError : main thread is not in main loop`

Comment: @constructor, my goal was to show the root of the problem, and that in Windows there is no such thing as a "tkinter dialog", except for the API calls to the native dialogs under the hood of the `tkinter`. It's well known that `tkinter` isn't a thread-safe thing on its own, therefore you should move `clr`-related stuff to the separate child thread/process and plan your communication between `tkinter` and `clr`. But that's another story. Long story short: final solution heavily depends on the design and requirements.

Comment: @constructor, anyway, from the point of view of the OP, they should have been separated initially - it's a bad idea to run some of the Matlab calculations in one thread with a graphical interface. However, if they were separated in the first place, then the described problem wouldn't occur!

Comment: @CommonSense
thank you very much for the explanation and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the code which you pasted on Pycharm 2018.1.3 with python-3.6.5 installed on win-7 64 bit machine. It works fine without any error. There are few bugs in 2017 version. Try upgrading to latest version of Pycharm