# C# Alternative to background worker for reporting progress and COM interop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker, excel-interop

Background:
I'm making a C# application to copy a range of cells into a bitmap image for reporting. All of my users have excel installed on their computer so the Excel COM interop is an easy way to access and render the sheets. I'd like the COM interop to work on a different thread so that it doesn't lock up my winforms UI. Initially, I tried background worker so that I can report progress to the UI as each sheet is processed. I am not trying to use multithreading to increase speed or to asynchronously process multiple workbooks. However, I've ran into two big issues.

- range.CopyPicture relies on the windows clipboard which causes a very sporadic race case.
- The excel interop is single threaded apartment but background worker uses a threadpool.

I've been reading into TAP (Task-based asynchronous pattern) and EAP (Event based asynchronous pattern) but I'm having trouble applying this info into my situation. What is the alternative that will allow both UI progress reporting and play nicely with the excel COM interop?

My current code using background worker:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object? sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    excelApp = new Excel.Application();

    Workbook workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookFilePath, ReadOnly: true);

    Worksheet mySheet = workbook.Sheets[1];

    worker.ReportProgress(10);

    Bitmap image = GenerateImageFromWorksheet(mySheet);

    image.Save(outputNamePath);
    
    workbook.Close(0);

    excelApp.Quit();

    worker.ReportProgress(100);
}

private Bitmap GenerateImageFromWorksheet(Worksheet mySheet)
{
    // A bunch of interop code

    Excel.Range myRange = mySheet.Range[mySheet.Cells[1, 1], mySheet.Cells[row, column]];

    myRange.CopyPicture(XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, XlCopyPictureFormat.xlBitmap);

    return new Bitmap(GetClipboardData());
}
```

EDIT:
This is different from the related question because it provides more context about the actual application of the solution rather than how to apply the abstract method. I am not asking how to create a STA thread with message pump but rather what asynchronous programming model is compatible with my technology.

Comment: Office apps (accessed via interop) **really** want to run in a foreground (/UI) context (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2). You are probably much better off using `async`/`await` (without `Task.Run`) to get this to work:

Comment: Rather use OpenXML for this than ancient, slow, and buggy COM interop.

Comment: @IanKemp I don't think OpenXML has the ability to render the document to a bitmap. I am not modifying the sheet in any way so it's features do not help me.

Comment: @Flydog57 My understanding is async/await will cause my gui to lock up unless using task.run. The office apps care about single thread apartments rather than being foreground and will work fine barring any user interaction [threading-support-in-office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/threading-support-in-office?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). This is a client side application so I don't see anything in that article I should be concerned with.

Comment: @KennyTK: in a sample WinForms app, create button and a button handler. Make the handler `async void` (rather that just `void`). Then add `await Task.Delay(5000); MessageBox.Show("X");` and note that the UI doesn't lock up. Try changing the call to `Delay` so that it calls `Thread.Sleep` instead (and you'll see what a locked up UI feels like). Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37419845/timeline and https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: @Flydog57 You're right. This entire problem stems from my misunderstanding of async/await and the message pump. A few additional resources for future travelers:
[ApartmentState for dummies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies?rq=3)
& [What is a message pump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222365/what-is-a-message-pump/2223270#2223270) which is a very similar issue.