# Non Blocking Download

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm new to Windows Phone 7 development, and am having a bit of trouble finding out how to download some data in the 'background', if you will. I know it is possible, because apps like ESPN, etc, display a "Loading ... .. ." while downloading their data, and the UI is still completely responsive. What I'm trying to do is download some Twitter data.

Here is what I have now, but it is blocking atm:

```
// Constructor:

// load the twitter data
WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=badreligion"));

// Callback function:

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error != null)
  {
    return;
  }

  XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

  TwitterListBox.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                               select new TwitterItem
                               {
                                 ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                 Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                 UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                               };

}
```

**EDIT:** Attempt at multithreading:

```
// in constructor
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(StartTwitterUpdate));

// other functions
private void StartTwitterUpdate()
{
  // load the twitter data
  WebClient twitter = new WebClient();

  twitter.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted);
  twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=badreligion"));
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Error != null)
  {
    return;
  }

  XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

  TwitterListBox.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                               select new TwitterItem
                               {
                                 ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                 Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                 UserName = tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                               };

}
```

**EDIT 2:** Using `HttpWebRequest`, as suggested by [Rico Suter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8029642/non-blocking-download/8044391#8044391), and with the help of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx) blog post, I think I've done it:

```
// constructor
StartTwitterUpdate();


private void StartTwitterUpdate()
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=badreligion"));

  request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(twitter_DownloadStringCompleted), request);
}

void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

  using (StreamReader streamReader1 = 
    new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      string resultString = streamReader1.ReadToEnd();

      XElement xmlTweets = XElement.Parse(resultString);

      Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
        TwitterListBox.ItemsSource = from tweet in xmlTweets.Descendants("status")
                                     select new TwitterItem
                                     {
                                       ImageSource = tweet.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
                                       Message = tweet.Element("text").Value,
                                       UserName = "@" + tweet.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value
                                     };
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is not blocking.  (That's what `Async` means)

Comment: @SLaks: I know that's what Async means, and I know it /shouldn't/ be blocking, but it is. Is it possible a different part of my app is blocking? Maybe the actual drawing of the list? It is set up as (i think) a binding? I've only been doing MS programming for about 4 hours total, so I hope I'm not asking something really obvious.

Comment: It shouldn't block. Isn't your callback function just taking a lot of time? In case you have a lot of data to pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options: `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient`. Both classes are downloading in the background. Only difference: With `WebClient` the method `twitter_DownloadStringCompleted` will be called in UI thread so the parsing of the data will block the UI.

If you use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) the method will be called in another thread but to set the data for data binding or directly to a control you have to use something like this:

```
void twitter_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // do your parsing with e.Result...
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
        // set your data (2) to UI
    });
}
```

The code in (2) will be called in UI thread. Set your progressbar to visible in `StartTwitterUpdate` and set your progress bar to invisible in (2).

Check out this classes to simplify http calls (POST, FILES, GZIP, etc):

http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Http

Answer (score 5):

I think the `WebClient` methods are partially blocking. The first part including DNS lookup is blocking, but the download itself is not.

See [C# async methods still hang UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726131/c-sharp-async-methods-still-hang-ui)

Personally I'd call this a bug in the .net API (or even worse: broken by design)

As a workaround you can start the download in a separate thread. I recommend using the tasks API for that.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
  ()=>
  {
      twitter.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=badreligion"));
  }
);
```

Not optimal, since it occupies a thread while performing the DNS lookup, but should be acceptable in practice.

---

I think another problem with your code is that the callback will not happen on the main thread, but on a threadpool thread. You need to use a `SynchronizationContext` that posts the event to the main thread.

Comment: That definitely sounds like what I'm dealing with, but I'm not sure exactly how to resolve it based off of the responses given in that thread.

Comment: I've updated my question, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm probably misunderstanding how to start a thread.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that [the Silverlight/WP7 version of the BeginGetResponse docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse(v=VS.95).aspx) does not contain the warning you mention in your other post.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I couldn't seem to get my project to find `Task`/`Tasks`. Is it perhaps not included in the WP7 library? Autocomplete wouldn't finish in VS2010 after `using System.Threading.` It was like it didn't know of the classes.

Comment: If anyone is trying to use [WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh138332.aspx) instead of the original method using .NET 4.5 then don't even bother, it'll block just the same (WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync and it's little brother too).