# STATHHREAD attribute required if application contains object that implements IDisposable

Tags: vb.net

I am looking at a number of Windows Forms applications that have no user interface and have no STA Thread (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.stathreadattribute.aspx) attribute above the main thread.

I have not created an COM components that are used in these applications.

I have read the following thread: [STAThread and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165316/stathread-and-multithreading).  Bruce states: "Apartment threading is a COM concept; if you're not using COM, and none of the APIs you call use COM "under the covers".  Is there a way of finding out if classes use COM: "under the covers"?

In the past I would simply look to see if the class implements IDisposable e.g. SQLConnection implements IDisposable so it must contain unmanaged resources i.e. COMcomponents.

Is it safe to say that if the Windows application or console application references an object that implements IDisposable, then the main thread should contain the STAThread attribute above it?

Comment: `IDisposable` is not necessarily an indication of COM usage. Maybe a runtime examination is all you can do because COM is typically late-bound.

Comment: @roger_rowland, thanks.  Can you clarify what you mean by a runtime examination? Reflector?

Comment: Not reflector but maybe sysinternals process explorer to see what modules are loaded. Look for COM dlls or OCX.