# How will STAThread affect my multi-threaded program

Tags: c#, multithreading, com, sta

I've recently encountered a STA-related error in my program when I tried to launch an `OpenFileDialog` in a WinForm. I've done some reading, and before I add the `[STAThread]` attribute to my main thread I want to know how it will affect my program's execution.
I am a foreigner to COM so not everything I read made sense to me. Some points that stuck with me are:

> The [STAThread] attribute defines the application as using a single-threaded apartment model.
>   More specifically, it changes the state of the application thread to be single-threaded.
>   http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=93
>
> The STA architecture can impose significant performance penalties when an object is accessed by many threads. Each thread's access to the object is serialized and so each thread must wait in line for its turn to have a go with the object.
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9190/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment-Pa

I understand the need for thread-safety but I still don't understand *what* STAThread does. In my program (which I inherited from another developer) the main thread launches several other threads, one of which initializes the UI forms - and I think this is where the problem arises. With `[STAThread]` added what happens to the new threads? Does this affect multi-thread communication for non-Windows objects?

The error occurs when I try to open an `OpenFileDialog` in one of my forms. I added the dialog to the form using the VS designer: it didn't work. I then attempted to create a dialog box in a global file which is run by the main thread and call that instance from my form. It had no effect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165316/stathread-and-multithreading

Comment: [This StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta) explains it very clear.

Comment: @icemanind I'm surprised that wasn't a suggested question when I was typing out my own. It's a good explanation but doesn't explain what happens to other spawned threads (if anything).

Comment: @ChristopheD my error message is `Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process`. I don't understand why I wasn't able to call the dialog box from the form on which I created it.

Comment: that atribute is used to indicate that this thread is a single-apartment thread. This is
used for COM interop, which some of the controls require to provide their functionality

Comment: @valsidalv, why are you trying to call `OpenFileDialog` from a secondary non-UI thread, in the first place?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[STAThread] or Thread.SetApartmentState() are a really, really big deal.  You make a **promise** to the operating system that you write code that is well-behaved.  It matters to lots and lots of code inside Windows as well as components you use that are not thread-safe.  Standard examples of such code are the Clipboard, Drag + Drop, the shell dialogs (like OpenFileDialog), components like WebBrowser and many Windows sub-components that are wrapped by .NET classes.

Thread-safety is always a big deal, writing truly thread-safe code is very, very difficult.  The .NET Framework itself accomplishes it very rarely.  Very basic classes list List<> are not thread-safe.

By making the *promise* to behave well, you must abide by the rules of writing code in a thread that reports itself to be an STA thread.  You *must* do two basic things:

1. You must pump a message loop.  Aka Application.Run() in a Winforms or WPF app.  A message loop is a basic mechanism by which you can get code to run on a *specific* thread.  It is the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem).  Which solves the thread-safety problem, if you call thread-unsafe code always from the same thread then it isn't unsafe anymore.
2. You must never block your thread.  Blocking an STA thread is *very* likely to cause deadlock.  Because it stops those chunks of code that are not thread-safe from being called.  There is core support for this in the CLR, blocking an STA thread with WaitOne() causes it to pump a message loop itself.

These requirements are easily met in a Winforms or WPF app.  They are class libraries that were completely designed to help you implement them.  Almost every single aspect about the way they behave was affected by it.

You **must** mark the Main() method in a GUI app as [STAThread].  Rock-hard requirement when it creates windows.

Creating another thread that displays a window is supported and possible.  This time you **must** call SetApartmentState() to switch to STA, it cannot be a thread-pool thread.  Getting this right is very difficult, in Winforms you'll get bitten badly by the SystemEvents class if you use certain kind of controls.  It has a knack to start raising its events on the wrong thread.  Debugging such a problem requires black-belt skills that [look like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents.userpreferencechanged.aspx).  That's suppose to scare you.